# Docker login works for stage: build but fails for stage: deploy in the same pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am experiencing an issue “Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device” in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. The pipeline has four stages build, test, review, and deploy, however, “$ docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY” works fine for ‘stage: build’, but fails for ‘stage: deploy’. Found this [article](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/error-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device/59936) so the 'master' branch is protected, but did not help.

```
build_job:
   stage: build
   image: docker:20.10.16
   services:
     - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
       alias: docker
   variables:
     #CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
     DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
     DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
     DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
   script:
     - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
     - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
     - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE


# LOGS: 
$ docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
```

```
deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
      alias: docker
  variables:
    #CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker run -d -p 3000:3000 $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  environment: 
    name: production/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    url: https://$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.example.com


#LOGS:
$ docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any help, please?
Thanks!

Comment: 2nd revision with some bonus over in the Gitlab forums: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/docker-login-works-for-stage-build-but-fails-for-stage-deploy-in-the-same-pipeline/84915/2?u=hakre

Answer (score 3):

> **TLDR:** Provide the right credentials, otherwise the error message might not tell you what went wrong.

> *Upfront summary of recommendations:*
>
> 1. Always quote the variables <sup>1</sup>, otherwise it is easy to miss if they are unset.
> 2. Provide the password via standard input (stdin), this is a better fit for CI/CD pipelines.

---

The *"Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device"* emitted by the `docker(1)` command for a command like yours in the gitlab job:

```
docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```

The message is a bit misleading because `docker login` is quite lax here. Even you specified to read the password as string from the command-line (`-p` or `--password` option), if the password is missing or wrong, `docker login` will *ask* for it.

As this makes no sense within a gitlab CI automation - there is no interactive terminal (TTY) - the `docker login` command is at least clever enough to realize that and quits with the bespoken error message.

So if you get that error, you were not able to properly provide the password.

### The Missing Credentials Docker Login Situation in Gitlab CI/CD

You can change the `docker login` command to make it a bit more robust, especially within CI runs.

Let's shortly review the usage and better understand the problem to then make some suggestions how to improve. From `docker login --help`:

```
Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]

Log in to a registry.
If no server is specified, the default is defined by the daemon.

Options:
  -p, --password string   Password
      --password-stdin    Take the password from stdin
  -u, --username string   Username
```

Given your original command-line:

```
docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```

and considering an error and all those three [Gitlab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) are empty, the command-line would look like the following:

```
docker login -u -p
```

That is login with the username "-p" to the default server.

You can simulate that on your own shell by running this command with standard-input closed:

```
$ 0<&- docker login -u -p
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

Exactly that error message.

#### Always quote `"$VARIABLES"`

Looking closer at the actual command-line, the error message is a reminder to **always quote the variables**<sup>1</sup>.  Also for explicitness use the options delimiter `--`:

```
docker login -u "$REGISTRY_USER" -p "$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" -- "$CI_REGISTRY"
```

In the error case those variables are empty the command then is:

```
docker login -u "" -p "" -- ""
```

The behaviour is still the same thought, the docker login command still tries hard, and it's not yet giving a good message.

> **NOTE:** It's not solving any of the problems incl. the messaging *but* we at least handle the case of empty or undefined variables,  thanks to the quoting they do not disappear any longer:
>
> ```
> 0<&- docker login -u "" -p "" -- ""
> Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
> ```

#### The `--password-stdin` option

Therefore within a non-interactive session (like the gitlab-runner) it is strongly recommended:

**Use the `--password-stdin` option.** Not only to prevent the warning in the case of a successful login but to make docker login to actually complain about the empty username in the first place! Also it allows to specify it *before* the username argument option to remove another ambiguity:

```
echo "$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login --password-stdin -u "$REGISTRY_USER" -- "$CI_REGISTRY"
```

Now even if the variables are missing, the command still fails in a good way:

```
echo "" | docker login --password-stdin -u "" -- ""
Must provide --username with --password-stdin
```

1. Always quote the variables <sup>1</sup>, otherwise it is easy to miss if they are unset.
2. Provide the password via standard input (stdin), this is a better fit for CI/CD pipelines.

---

***Remarks:***

1. An earlier version of the answer suggested to quote the variables with single-quotes (`'`), which turned out to be wrong after [Franks' answer with the final conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026768/367456). Better than single-quotes for this Gitlab CI job with a Linux/Unix (shell) `script`, the variables need to be quoted with double quotes (`"`) instead, as they are substituted by the shell and not - as assumed earlier - when the shell script is generated by the runner for its executor. Under that wrong impression I had considered single-quotes a better fit as their content won't be substituted by the shell then, but substituting within the shell is much better now (and much more stable/safe by the gitlab runner to do it this way now as I think about it).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, which helped me solve the issue.

Comment: @Frank: That's good to read. I couldn't tell, so I'm still curious: What turned the secrets empty in the first place? And feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: answering here below as 'answering my question' because comments don't allow Markdown formatting.

Comment: @Frank, they do, but limited only. I'm also fine if you answer your own question and even mark that as the solution if from your perspective it's a better fit. Just keep your future self _and_ future visitors in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Following the @hakre explanation here above, the solution leads me to two subsequent errors, however, it helped me solve the "Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device".

First, by adding the following command in the pipeline:

```
$ echo '$REGISTRY_PASSWORD' | docker login --password-stdin -u '$REGISTRY_USER' -- '$CI_REGISTRY'
```

It started throwing the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://$CI_REGISTRY/v2/": dial tcp: lookup $CI_REGISTRY: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So, modified the command to:

```
$ echo '$REGISTRY_PASSWORD' | docker login --password-stdin -u '$REGISTRY_USER' https://gitlab.com
```

In which started throwing the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://gitlab.com": unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Thus, created a personal access [token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), which solved the issue:

```
$ docker login -u <username> -p <personal_access_token> $CI_REGISTRY
Login Succeeded
```

Comment: This is perhaps also a mistake of mine: I was under the impression that Gitlab CI/CD variables would be resolved when the shell-script is generated, your answer somewhat reminds me that this was assumed too quick. I'll take a look how I can improve my answer about that, probably the better suggestion is using double-quotes.

Comment: @hakre, again thank you very much for your detailed explanations and help. Appreciated!