# How to run project with Gitlab CI registry variables?

Tags: django, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, .env

Can you explain. I have Gitlab runner and now I am configuring CI/CD using one guide. It says that runner requires the image names in `docker-compose.yml` to be named like this:

```
$CI_REGISTRY/organisation/path-to-project/project_image:$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

I put this value in a variable in the `.env` file. But now when I run `docker compose up` - error pops up - says `$CI_REGISTRY`, `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` and `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` are not set. What should I do in this case? Everything was working fine before CI/CD was connected.

```
level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
Error response from daemon: no such image: organisation/path-to-project/project_image:-: invalid reference format
```

At the same time `docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY` in `before_script` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` works and variable values are calculated from somewhere.

```
image: docker/compose:alpine-1.28.0

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apk add make
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - cp $ENV $(pwd)/src/.env

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make build push
  tags:
    - job:build
  only:
    - main
  environment:
    name: production

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - make pull down migrate up
  tags:
    - job:deploy
  only:
    - main
  environment:
    name: production
```

`$ENV` in `before_script` is variable on Gitlab.

Here is `docker-compose.yml` (`${IMAGE_NAME}` - variable from `.env`):

```
services:
  app1:
    build: .
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    # ...

  app2:
    build: .
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    # ...
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm just getting started with CI/CD.

Comment: So you have IMAGE_NAME=$CI_REGISTRY/organisation/path-to-project/project_image:$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA in .env?

Comment: @swilvx yes, .env in the same directory with .gitlab-ci.yml and docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

This is about **Docker Compose** <sup>1</sup> .

The `env_file` option defines environment variables that will be available inside the container only <sup>2,3</sup> .

If however, you want it to be interpreted during the Gitlab CI/CD execution of the `before_script` / `build.script` or `deploy.script` commands, you need to have a file named `.env` placed at the root next to your `docker-compose.yml` file **unless** you use the `--env-file` option in the CLI <sup>4</sup> .

Try this on your own shell first, let's setup an example composition with a .env file:

```
$ printf 'name: ${EXAMPLE}\n' > docker-compose.EXAMPLE.yml
$ printf 'EXAMPLE=c-to-the-i-to-the-c-to-the-d\n' > .env.EXAMPLE
$ docker compose --env-file .env.EXAMPLE --file docker-compose.EXAMPLE.yml config
name: c-to-the-i-to-the-c-to-the-d
services: {}
```

The same it works when the Gitlab runner execute any of the script commands.

> **NOTE:** *Docker Compose V1 vs. V2*: You have not shown the concrete `docker-compose(1)` commands in your question. The `--env-file` command-line option may only be available with `docker compose ...` and **not** `docker-compose ...`. If you're using the `docker-compose` command change to the `docker` command with the `compose` plugin (availabe as sub-command).

### Gitlab CI/CD `before_script` Docker Registry and Docker Compose Configuration Example

Here an example based on your Gitlab CI/CD configurations' `before_script` with some notes, the numbers in the comments relate to the numbered list below the example:

```
before_script:
  - apk add make
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login --password-stdin -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -- "$CI_REGISTRY" # (1)
  - cp "$ENV" ./src/.env # (2)
  - docker compose --env-file ./src/.env --file docker-compose.yml config # (3)
```

1. Always quote variables. Handle the non-happy path (e.g. variables are unset) *([here the story for docker login in gitlab ci/cd and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76018767/367456))*
2. Always quote variables, again, and no need for `$(pwd)` (which then should be quoted, again, as well: `"$(pwd)"`). Less is better, often and then more often in the long run.
3. Run `docker compose config` to see if your configuration is as it should.

### `$ make install-local-runner`

As you're getting started with Gitlab CI/CD, bring it next to you if you have not yet: [Instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/). Roughly 500MB in size, you have `gitlab-runner exec` etc. afterwards and can actually deal with all those issues before they even touch ground far away and much later (*[Villarriba comes to mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhwjCMpywVg)*: `make local && make party`).

---

1. https://docs.docker.com/compose/
2. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#env_file
3. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4189#issuecomment-263458253
4. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with-an-env-file